# Custom Tab on Facebook Page

Tags: facebook

I wanted to know if there is a way of adding **custom tabs** as shown on Facebook PAges or Profiles?? [image attached: I've modified the image through Paint[image: ]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a photoshop of a Facebook User profile, not a Page, but either way:
No, there's no way to, via the API or Facebook's own interface, add custom functionality or buttons to profiles or pages.

Comment: Yes. Its my own profile page. I couldn't find a better way to ask the question.